# 2D Heat equation solved with finite element method converges in skewed way

Tags: finite-element, heat-transfer

I tried to solve the 2D heat equation with the finite element method, using triangles as elements. Currently generated by a Delaunay triangulation. The base function I'm currently using is basically just the first barycentric coordinate. Assuming a triangle with $a, b, c$ as vertices:
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{(b_y - c_y) (x - c_x) + (c_x - b_x) (y - c_y)}{(b_y - c_y)  (a_x - c_x) + (c_x - b_x) (a_y - c_y)}
$$
For integrating the equation I'm using a Gauss4x4 from [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/quadrature_rules_tri/quadrature_rules_tri.html](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/datasets/quadrature_rules_tri/quadrature_rules_tri.html) over the unit triangle.
To transform the triangle($u, v$ are coordinates on the unit triangle):
$$
p = a + (b - a) u + (c - a) v
$$
and its determinant:
$$
(b_x - a_x) (c_y - a_y) - (c_x - a_x) (b_y - a_y)
$$
And the weak form of the equation, if the integral over the boundary is zero:
$$
-\int_{\Omega} (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}) (\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})= \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}v
$$
Now the problem I'm having is that starting from a "heat" patch in the middle the heat flows to the upper left and lower right corner first. Below is picture from the initial state and later when the heat flows into the corners, forming in the long run a diagonal band.

[image: initial heat distribution]

[image]

I expected the heat to spread in all directions equally. Looking more uniform and like a circle.

Without me posting too much code, may there be an explanation why this is happening?

Comment: The weak form you have written is incorrect. The LHS should be $-\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot \nabla v \ dx$. If this isn't a typo, this may be causing the issue because the weak form you wrote isn't rotationally invariant and will diffuse in different directions unequally. I'm not putting this as an answer because I'm not sure if it's a typo or not. I can provide more details if you confirm this.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that weak form seems to translate to $\partial^2_1 u + 2\partial_{12}^2 u + \partial_2^2 u = \partial_t u$ rather than $\Delta u = \partial_t u$. In cleaner terms, $\nabla \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \nabla u$ rather than $\nabla \cdot \nabla u$.

Comment: What would be the correct definition of the LHS then, in terms of partial derivatives? I'm pretty sure that this not a typo but rather  my mistake

Comment: $-\int u_xv_x + u_yv_y \ dxdy$

Comment: Additionally, can you confirm whether the $y$-direction in your image is increasing from down to up or decreasing from down to up? With the weak form you've written one can see that no diffusion will occur in the direction $(-1,1)^T$ and will only occur in the direction $(1,1)^T$. This matches with your image if $y$ is decreasing from bottom to top

Comment: Yep thats it. Thank you. I don't know how I ended up with my solution. You are correct about the coordinates.

Comment: You should write a short answer to this question so it can be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the LHS of the weak form was wrong, the correct one is:
$$
-\int u_{x} v_{x} + u_{y} v_{y} dxdy
$$
Instead of
$$
-\int (u_{x}+u_{y}) (v_{x}+v_{y})dxdy
$$
Thanks to whpowell96 for spotting the mistake